# Open Graph (beta) - using global actions and global objects together with custom ones

Tags: object, action, global, facebook-opengraph, beta

My scenario is the following:

I want to create a custom object called Music Video (because I don't see a global one) create a property for it of object type Song (I assume there's a global object Song, with artist, title, album, etc properties) and I also want to hook it up to the global action Watch.
Is this possible? If not, what workaround do you suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The built-in watch action can only be performed on objects of the type 'movie', 'tv_show', 'episode' or 'video.other'. As these are built-in objects, you can't modify them by adding references to other objects such as a Song object.

You have two options:

1) model your music videos as og:type 'video.other' and publish to the built-in watch action - in this case you get all the benefits of using a built-in action, but you can't reference Songs or any other objects in your actions.

2) create a custom music video object, link it to a built-in Song object using and object property, and publish to a custom 'playing' action. This option gives you full control of timeline aggregations, object references and action references, but you can't launch this type of integration publicly until Open Graph is out of Beta, which will happen sometime soon after Timeline has rolled out.

Comment: Thanks Simon! Unfortunately I'm not able to see the Song object. Any idea? Check a screenshot [here](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/1632371/Screen%20shot%202011-11-23%20at%204.17.56%20PM.png).

Answer (score 0):

Sadly you can't use a global action with a non-global object since consumers of the global action wouldn't know how to parse your special object.

Just make your own action when posting music videos.